# aws api-gateway-secure-pet-store example giving signature mismatch error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

The sample project - `api-gateway-secure-pet-store` (an example of `cognito`, `IAM`, `Lambda` and `API Gateway) mentioned [here](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store) gives  following error:

When executing a login request, I receive the following credentials :

```
"credentials": {
  "accessKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "secretKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sessionToken": "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",
  "expiration": 1462280810000
}
```

But when I call the `Pets` request with above credentials and below URL/JSON:

URL: https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/devTest/pets

JSON in Body:

```
{
  "action": "com.amazonaws.apigatewaydemo.action.CreatePetDemoAction",
  "body": {
    "petId":"4",
    "petType":"RabbitSumit",
    "petName":"TabbitSumit",
    "petAge":"41"
  }
}
```

by entering above parameters , it does the following

```
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/devTest/pets\n\ncontent-length:212\ncontent-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nhost:XXXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20160503T121516Z\nx-amz-security-token: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\n\ncontent-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token\n82d7b00fc60e9684db97202b877091a3836e091224a5a8bf4567080e104e4459'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20160503T121516Z\n20160503/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request\nd6d9d29069c6575ec4510dfab1268f2ba1697a876a660c4564fe8398674f3c97'\n"}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't post access key and secret key information online...

Comment: @MarkB I have updated (actually that was a temporary random,  accesskey and secret key)

Comment: Based on the documentation(https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store), you would have followed to configure an IAM Role with following stuff (Amazon Cognito Identity,Amazon DynamoDB,AWS Lambda,Amazon CloudWatch Logs).

Say you would have given the name to this 'PetRole'.

Go to the Swagger.Yaml file,(in the source code) and add this ARN of 'PetRole'. to 'credentials' of x-amazon-apigateway-integration for all paths ( Its documentation says to add ARN of 'PetRole'. to credentials of only /users and /login, but I add this to others as well, e.g. for /pets and then it worked )